# multiple routes with same url based on condition

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

We have an angular application with an external part for external users and an internal part for internal users.

We would like them to have the same urls with different components (internal components are completely different than external components).

Is this possible with Angular? If I use a guard it will not go further than the first route. If a use a matcher it doesn't work well with nested routes...

Here is some pseudo code of what is needed:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
   // internal zone
   { path = '', children: internRoutes, [condition checking something on global service] },
   // external zone
   { path = '', children: externRoutes, [condition checking something on global service] }
];
```

Comment: Can you share some code

Comment: I updated the comment. I tried this code by  using a matcher but it didn't work well with nested routes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Module that handles what module should be load by providing the ROUTES of the RouterModule using the useFactory provider of Angular.

The code could be something like that.

```
// HandlerModule

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ROUTES,
      useFactory: configHandlerRoutes,
      deps: [SessionService],
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})


export class HandlerModule {}

export function configHandlerRoutes(sessionService: SessionService) {
  let routes: Routes = [];
  if (sessionService.isLoggedIn()) {
    routes = [
      {
        path: '', loadChildren: () => import('app/member/member.module').then(mod => mod.MemberModule)
      }
    ];
  } else {
    routes = [
      {
        path: '', loadChildren: () => import(app/guest/guest.module).then(mod => mod.GuestModule)
      }
    ];
  }
  return routes;
}
```

Then in your AppRoutingModule the module of the path '' is going to be the HandlerModule:

```
// AppRoutingModule

 {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('app/handler/handler.module').then(mod => mod.HandlerModule)
}
```

After in the SessionService you have to update the Router.config when the value that provides the method isLoggedIn changes, because the application will only load the page (module) that had loaded the first time. This is because the function “configHandlerRoutes” use by the useFactory provider in the HandlerModule is only executed the first time we navigate to the “” path and after that the Angular Router already know which module he has to load.

In conclusion in the SessionService you have to do:

```
 export class SessionService {
  private loggedIn: boolean;
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.loggedIn = false;
  }

  public isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.loggedIn;
  }

  public setLoggedIn(value: boolean): void {
    const previous = this.loggedIn;
    this.loggedIn = value;
    if (previous === this.loggedIn) {
      return;
    }
    const i = this.router.config.findIndex(x => x.path === '');
    this.router.config.splice(i, 1);
    this.router.config.push(
      {path: '', loadChildren: () => import('app/handler/handler.module').then(mod => mod.HandlerModule)}
    );
  }
}
```

That's it.

If you want another reference here is an article where they use the same approach: https://medium.com/@german.quinteros/angular-use-the-same-route-path-for-different-modules-or-components-11db75cac455

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution.

In the app routing module we just assign an empty array (forRoot) in our case because the entire application is split in external and internal.

```
 @NgModule({
    imports: [
          // by default we have no routes
          // the app component will inject the routes based on I or E (same URL different modules/components)
          RouterModule.forRoot([], { enableTracing: true })
    ],
    ...
 })
```

In our app component we add the route with different child routes dependening on the condition (internal or external).

```
constructor(private router: Router, private state: State, ...) {
    // here we add the routes which is different based on zone (dynamic routes)
    this.router.config.unshift(
        {
            path: '',
            children: this.state.zone == 'I' ? internRoutes : externRoutes
        }
    );
```